# How to load .nib into view?

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4, interface-builder

I made this program in Java and now I'm porting it over to a Mac App and when it opens I have a nib open that displays instructions, and when the user clicks "Next" I want it to open my second view and close the first one. I made the second nib complete with everything, but I just don't know how to load it or from where.

I understand Objective-C code relatively well, but when it comes to using Interface Builder and making guis I get confused.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this way: -

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXibFileName" owner:self];
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [NSBundle's Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004013) and `+ (BOOL)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)aNibName owner:(id)owner`:

```
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"YourOtherNib" owner:self];
```

*By using "self" as the owner, everything connected to the "File's Owner" in your NIB file will be connected to self's IBOutlets*

*Note:* You can find more information about NIB file [in Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) that should help you understanding how NIB files work.

Answer (score 0):

I have created library which allow you to load custom view from nib, all you need to do is set File's Owner to Class File. Check it here: https://github.com/inspace-io/INSNibLoading